# Custom UI Button not shwing title

Tags: ios, swift

I created a custom UI Button class in swift for a follow button, however it is not showing the button title

My code

```
@IBDesignable
public class GradientButton: UIButton {

override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layoutGradientButtonLayer()
}

// MARK: Private
private func layoutGradientButtonLayer() {
    let layer = UIView()
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 191, y: 257, width: 66.6, height: 24)
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 66.6, height: 24)
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red: 0.09, green: 0.85, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.87, blue: 0.68, alpha: 1).cgColor
    ]
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.78, y: 1)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.15, y: 1)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.setTitle("Follow", for: UIControlState.normal)

   }
  }
```

The button appears small width and doesn't have any "Follow" text in it

Comment: Try to change **TextColor**. Add code of how you use that button.

Comment: I have tried your code and works fine, I think there's some minor mistake in the use of that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below code you will see title:

```
self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

change to

```
self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

[image]